# How can I generate a Java factory at compile time?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an interface that has been implemented maybe 50 times and my app will keep on evolving with new implementations. These implementations should be loaded depending on their name (which is a constant available in each implementation).

I want to avoid using reflection at runtime (because the [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) lib pulls 3Mb of dependencies and I need to keep my jar as small as possible) and I would also like to avoid having to add an entry to my factory each time an Implementation is added.

So I was wondering: how can I do this automatically at compile time ? I would basically only need to build a map of `Implmentation.NAME => ImplmentationConstructor`

Thanks

**Edit:** What I'm really looking for here is to not have to care about writing the code to load those classes. So that could mean having the factory generated automatically on compile (full code generation) or using some kind of ServiceLoader-like tool that supports auto-generating the required files and supporting constructors with arguments. For now the easiest solution I could come up with is to use reflection in my Unit Tests to check that all implementations are accessible through my constructor and if not, output in the console the code that needs to be put in my factory so that they are.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) can be used to manage (and select from) large number of implementations of an Interface. You add a file, named for your interface, that contains the full qualified name of all your implementations to:-

```
 META-INF/services/com.my.interface.MyInterface
```

The ServiceLoader can load and manage all the implementations for you. In your factory method, you can select the most appropriate implementation and return it.

```
 ServiceLoader<MyInterface> impls  = ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface.class);

for(MyInterface impl : impls) {
     //iterating over each impl
 }
```

Comment: In addition, you could use [Google AutoService](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) to generate the file in `META-INF` automatically for you so that you cannot forget to update it.

Comment: This solution would indeed be great provided there is a way to automatically generate the META-INF files but it seems Google AutoService doesn't work in an eclipse+maven environment. Any advice about that ? Thanks

Comment: You can probably do generation at build time (via Maven or Gradle) and then also trigger it on an adhoc basis (again via Maven or Gradle) when you need it (e.g. when a test fails in your IDE). They only need to be generated once per class.

Comment: I actually tested this without the auto generation for now and I'm having an exception because my constructors require parameters. It seems it's a requirement for `ServiceLoader`. I could add a subclass for each implementation that would be some kind of loader-with-param but that adds a lot of code and that's what i'd like to avoid: having to add some specific code for loading each time a new implementation is created.

Comment: If you need to pass parameters, probably what you want to register are Implementations of a Factory Interface rather than the actual implementations of your current interface themselves. Then have your ServiceLoader Based Factory chose the correct Factory to instantiate it's own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The classic factory pattern can be done easily and flexibly with `enum`s.

```
// What my factory can make.
interface Stuff {

}

// Some concrete implementations of Stuff.
private static class RollsRoyce implements Stuff {

    public RollsRoyce() {
    }
}

private static class Boeing implements Stuff {

    public Boeing() {
    }
}

// Each element in the factory must be able to make Stuff.
interface MakesStuff {

    Stuff makeOne();
}

enum Factory implements MakesStuff {

    Car {

                @Override
                public Stuff makeOne() {
                    return new RollsRoyce();
                }

            },
    Plane {
                @Override
                public Stuff makeOne() {
                    return new Boeing();
                }

            };

    // Special for making from a String name.
    public static Stuff make(String type) {
        // Will throw an exception if the name is not recognised.
        return Factory.valueOf(type).makeOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i'd like to avoid creating manually. What i'm looking for here is a way to automate the generation of that kind of factory on compile.

Comment: @Crystark - Perhaps some form of annotation would be useful.